# Decryption doesn't work for records querying with decrypted value on encrypted one

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js

I have an user table where i need to store email in encrypted format. I am able to do that by setting value encrypted to true in User model. But when i am trying to get that data based on the email id. I am passing email id in plain text format without encrypted value and trying to find record with that value. But i am not able to find that always value is empty.

Is there any way to query record with with decrypted value and value stored is in encrypted format??

Following are the code snippet i am trying to do.

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    //  ╔═╗╦═╗╦╔╦╗╦╔╦╗╦╦  ╦╔═╗╔═╗
    //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║║║║║ ║ ║╚╗╔╝║╣ ╚═╗
    //  ╩  ╩╚═╩╩ ╩╩ ╩ ╩ ╚╝ ╚═╝╚═╝
    email: { 
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      isEmail: true,
      encrypt: true,
      maxLength: 512,
    }
  }
}
```

Saving record in table

```
await User.create({email: 'abc@domain.com'})
```

Finding record with this email

```
let userData = await User.find({email: 'abc@domain.com'}).decrypt();
console.log('user Data', userData)
```

Output i got is empty array instead of array with matching record

```
user data []
```

I also tried without decrypt. It is also giving empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the entire point of encrypting database fields like email is to make it very difficult for cybercreeps to search for particular values.

You can try encrypting your search value before searching.... something like this.

```
const emailEncrypted = 'abc@domain.com'.encrypt()
let userData = await User.find({email: emailEncrypted}).decrypt()
console.log('user Data', userData)
```

Comment: There is no method something like this in sails js and it is throwing error

Comment: In that case you're stuck reading and decrypting all your email values one by one, looking for the one that matches. Encrypted-at-rest columns are fundamentally unsuitable for searching.